# Don't sanitize HTML when inserting text from MS Access Into SQL Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

My Application is basically an Access front end with a sql database in the backend.

I have a textfield in which i can write text. If i put new lines there, I can see that in the SQL database, there is a  inserted for formatting.

BUT when i write a  there, the  is sanitized and thus not displayed correctly later on.

Example:

```
eins 
absatz
custom <div></div>
```

is saved as
`<div>eins</div> <div>absatz</div> <div>custom&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</div>`

I actually don't know how to prevent that from happening, it seems like acces is doint that automatecally.

The access is version 2016 and the sql server is a mcrosoft SQL server Developer

My goal was the the user could type his own HTML for formatting for example

---

and then this HTML is stored normally as the autogenrated html in the database, to be displayed correctly when exporting data to pdf.

Comment: Probably, your textbox is set to _Rich Text_ which is HTML-like. Adjust that to plain text.

Comment: thanks a lot @Gustav ! Now the HTML stays in the database at least, although some are still not displayed, but i think thats because access wont render all element.

Comment: Yes, it only supports a subset of HTML.